# typed not working on github pages

Tags: jquery, jsfiddle, typed

I am trying to use typed on my github pages site. It does not work on the site but if I copy the code into a jsfiddle it does work. Why is that?

```
github page: http://materechm.github.io/

github code: github.com/materechm/materechm.github.io

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/albburtsev/8CbL2/
```

Comment: is code inside a load event or ready handler so element exists when code runs? fiddle does that by the preset default

Answer (score 0):

Swap these two lines:

```
<script src="typed.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
```

You need to include jQuery first.

Also, you are including typed twice, remove this line:

```
<script src="js/typed.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```